# How to edit resources.arsc

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm relatively new to Android Studio and I need to change the name of an app itself.

So I looked in the manifest and it says:

```
 android:label="@ref/0x7f040017"
```

I have looked everywhere for this mystery declaration of strings. The app I am trying to edit has no "values" folder under res and I have spent about an hour browsing the APK in Android Studio trying to find where it could be.

I have a strong feeling it is in the resources.arsc file but Android Studio will not let me edit it but shows it as a file with a question mark in the upper right corner. My research tells me there is no other program that opens these .arsc file.

So, how do I edit it?

Thanks in advance for any attempts at solving my foolish problem

Comment: Sounds as if you do not have the sourcecode but are trying to modify the APK itself.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm trying to do. Is there any way I can?